# How to Reduce the Boldness Slightly for Cambria Font in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-word-2013

I have a document where I use Cambria and would've preferred not to have used bold at all but I can't use caps so persistently in the following setup (font size is 10 throughout):

> Title: all-caps Spacing expanded 1 point, line underneath
>
> Heading: all-caps
>
> Sub-headings: all-caps Scale compressed 95%
>
> Sub-sub headings: bold Scale compressed 90%
>
> Additional information for sub-sub headings: Normal text, Scale compressed 90%

The 90% compression for bold is only to reduce the thickness of it because when printed, bold sticks out the most.

I feel it looks odd though because mostly I have the first word of a sentence as a heading -- immediately next to which the sentence begins. The compression makes the heading appear smaller than what follows.

Is there some other way for reducing the thickness of the font in bold for Cambria? Using Spacing instead of Scale brings the letters together without reducing their thickness, so that doesn't feel like the answer either.

Comment: instead of using "bold" and resizing, why not just use a different colour for those words than what's used for the standard text?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Because it's actually a resume. Although I did make the heading colored, adding color anywhere else works against it.

Comment: I meant like a slightly lighter/darker gray/black. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I did try that. I kept the main text all black but changed headings to lighter shades. Looked very odd to me that the heading should be lighter than the text. The bold is what really threw the whole thing off actually -- a light, thin, compressed all-caps heading above a dark thick bold one looked awful. Lightening the bold text didn't help either.

Comment: Can you use Calibri or a different font?